# How can I remove the moz-extension:// in the popup window Firefox extension created?

Tags: javascript, firefox

Currently, I'm developing an Firefox extension app. It will open a html file in a new popup window. When the poup window opened, it shows the title as format: "moz-extensions://", does anyone know how can I remove the prefix, the "moz-extension://"?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer

According to [this bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1296365) you **can't** currently do anything about it. It is present to prevent spoofing/phishing attacks against the user (acting like the popup is part of a UI).

#### Statement (Quote):

> We've been trying to make it clear that when something happens, the
> reason for it is clear to the end user. The ability to create a popup
> with no URL bar means that there could be absolutely no info to the
> user.

#### Custom Solution

If you want to have a popup with a custom title you would be better off creating your own HTML/CSS solution!